# PHP, JQuery Form submit redirect to another page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post

I have two forms in one page, registration and login. If a user try to enter a username into the "register_username" field, then on-blur, ajax check if this username already taken. It's all working properly. but I found out that if this ajax-call has been made, and then you click submit on the **login** form, it's redirect to the php-ajax page instead of the form-proccess php page.

I'm using Code-Ignitier as PHP framework, JQuery as javascript library and that's it. any additional information i'll try to deliver if i asked to do so. thank you very much.

**Edit:**
//Javascript code:

```
$('#register_username').live('blur',function() {
 $.post('ajax/username_taken', {'register_username':$(this).val() },
 function(result) {
  if(result) {
   $('#register_username').addClass('error');
  }
  else {
   $('#register_username').removeClass('error');
  }
 });
}
```

//Php code

```
echo form_open('form/login',$form_attr);
echo ....
echo form_submit($submit_attr);
echo form_close();
echo form_open('form/register',$form_attr);
echo ....
echo form_submit($submit_attr);
echo form_close();
```

*NOTE:*
This is all simplified, the forms are actually on different views, only register has a controller

Comment: Could you show your code or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of the issue?

Comment: I'll try to do that. Edit: it's almost impossible (as far as i know) to do a working jsfiddle of this, but i will edit the question and add actual code example

Comment: Show us your javascript and the form code. There might be some issue with setting the action of the form or wrong button is clicked.

Comment: The "action" of the form is set properly (as you can see in the Php code in the question).

Answer (score 1):

I'm just blind-guessing since you didn't provide much info. It seems that your javascript overrides your submit button's click event so try adding this in your `function(result)` and see if anything changes:

```
$('submit_button_selector').unbind();
```

Ofcourse, change $('XXX') part with your button selector, generally it should be like `$('#my_form).find(':submit')`

Its really a blindshot and more info would help a lot.

Comment: This didn't work. What details you missing? I know it might be a confusing question, i'm confused too. if you want me to add something, I'll do what I can

Comment: Could you give me full javascript code? You can paste it on http://hastebin.com/ or something.

Comment: remove line #126. 'return send;'
If still isn't behaving as it should, please add at that line following code: `alert($('#register_form').prop('action'));` and paste the output here.

Comment: The problem arise when clicking on submit of the **login** form, so should i put the alert there? (for now, no javascript assigned to the login form, i've tried to assign the submit function but it didn't change the situation)

Comment: Oh my.....i didn't realize there were 2 forms........can you by any way provide whole code packed in a .zip/.tar.gz/.rar archive? By whole code I mean your HTML page + all JavaScript included on it. This should be really simple matter, and solution is probably dead-simple too.

Comment: It's actually pretty complicated to do that, since it's combined with different controllers, js files, php libraries, models and views. I just thinking as I'm writing... maybe it's the cache of the ajax post request? how do i clear the cache?

Comment: I don't need PHP or libraries, just give me HTML source code and javascript you made manually (Open page->View Page Source). You clear cache in your browser....but I really don't think it's the case.